# Blackberry Bold- Unable to recognize URLs and even custom patterns registered

Tags: regex, blackberry, pattern-recognition

We have a blackberry native app deployed on a `BB Bold 9700 (OS Version: 5.0)`

The app registers a custom pattern of the form `string://[0-9]*` . Strings matching the pattern get highlighted but the app does not receive the complete string

Also, with URLs recognized and highlighted, when launched, the `BB browser` receives only a partial string - `http://`

This bug is observed with `BB Bold 9700 (OS Version: 5.0)` only.

Couple of more questions

1. Is there way to find all system patterns registered with a blackberry device?
2. How does blackberry resolve conflict if a text is matched by more than one pattern?

in my case both texts "`http://urlline`" and "`string://customtext`" got clipped to "`http:// and string`" respectively.

Comment: Please post the code where you declare the regex and how you use it.

Comment: In the autostartup entry point of the app, we set the pattern                    if (args[0].equals("startUp")) {String pattern = "MyString://(\\d{1,2})\\,(\\d{7})";
int patternType = PatternRepository.PATTERN_TYPE_REGULAR_EXPRESSION;
   MyMatchMenuItem[] menuItems = { new MyMatchMenuItem(100) };  PatternRepository.removePatterns(application);PatternRepository.addPattern(application, pattern, patternType,menuItems);}   Invoke app through new entry point and recognized string when launched with menu item ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("MyApp.altEntry?" + context.toString());

Comment: Thast a weird regex you are using. I don't understand why are you escaping the comma. Do you expect to match strings like `"MyString://41,57"` ?

Comment: If that's the case, I suggest you this one: `"MyString://\\d{1,2},\\d7"`

Comment: This is the exact regex "[sS][tT][rR][iI][nN][gG]://(\\d{1,2})\\,(\\d{7})". Also can you help me on my other questions

Comment: I'm a little confused.  The regex you've posted appears to be expecting url's like `string://12,3456789` (digits, not letters), but the example url you posted was `string://customtext` (letters, not digits).

Answer (score 1):

What I'm about to propose is trivial, I'm aware of it, but did you try:

```
\w+\:\/\/[\w\d\.\,\:\;]+
```

This would match a string before colon, the colon, the double slash and whatever letter or number or punctuation after it (obviously you can furtherly specialize the expression).

I'm not a BlackBerry developer, so I'm not able to respond to your other questions, I apologize for that.

Anyways, for every doubt or clarification you could rely on [this site here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).